# user authentication angularjs single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have created angularjs application with HTML and Javascript. But now I need to secure the application. If any request comes to any html page (or html templates or javascript):

- /main
- /products
- /categories

it should be redirect to login page, if user not authenticated. I am not using Asp.net or PHP or Java pages. I can publish my app on linux platform.

How can I secure my angularjs single page application.

Comment: There is dozens of questions related to this. Please search a little... keywords : angular-app or http-auth-interceptor

Comment: What do you have in the server side?

Comment: server os is ubuntu, and installed nginx + PHP, apache is not installed

Comment: Where are you going to check if the user exists and have access to the application? Where dou you have your valid users list?

Comment: are you suggesting here that your application is 100% client side logic, without a single call to a server anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The best that you can do with this is check for user authentication on every route change. But what ever you do client side authentication is very easy to by pass. but then also this can be the pseudo code:

```
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.error = null;
        if (!Auth.authorize(next.access)) {//check if the user is authorized to go to next page
            if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) $location.path('/');//if not authorized and is logged in then send him to home page 
            else                  $location.path('/login');//if not logged in ask for login
        }
    });
```

In order to get good flexibility try using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and the is a github project that can help you get started [angular-client-side-auth](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth).